# Why is my Spring Boot converter not working when others are

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I have not been able to figure out why some of my Spring Boot converters are not working. I have made a couple of converters that are working implemented the convert method, extended the WebMvcConfigurer overrode the addFormatters method and added all the converters there. some of th converters are working but I had to include some of my repos in the converter class as data from them is used in the conversion.
some example code

```
    //this one does work
@Component
class ReviewToDtoConverter: Converter<Review, ReviewDto> {
    override fun convert(review: Review): ReviewDto {
        return ReviewDto(review)
    }
}

//this one does not work
@Component
class DtoToReviewConverter: Converter<ReviewDto,Review> {

    @field:Autowired
    lateinit var userRepo: UserRepo

    @field:Autowired
    lateinit var productRepo: ProductRepo

    override fun convert(reviewDto: ReviewDto): Review? {

        return Review(
            reviewDto = reviewDto,
            user = try {userRepo.findByIdUser(reviewDto.userId ?: throw UserNotProvidedException("The User was not provided"))}
            catch (e: EmptyResultDataAccessException)
            { throw UserNotFoundException("The user could not be found")},
            product = try {productRepo.findByUpc(reviewDto.upc)}
            catch (e: EmptyResultDataAccessException)
            {throw ProductNotFoundException("The product could not be found")}
        )
    }
}
```

and where i am adding the converters

```
@Configuration
class MvcConfig: WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addFormatters(registry: FormatterRegistry) {
        registry.addConverter(DtoToOrderConverter())
        registry.addConverter(OrderToDtoConverter())
        registry.addConverter(UserToDtoConverter())
        registry.addConverter(DtoToUserConverter())
        registry.addConverter(DtoToProductConverter())
        registry.addConverter(ProductToDtoConverter())
        registry.addConverter(ReviewToDtoConverter())
        registry.addConverter(DtoToReviewConverter())
        super.addFormatters(registry)

    }

}

@Component
class MyConversionService:DefaultConversionService(), ConversionService{

}
```

I had to add the MyConversionService class because i was getting an error around spring not know which bean to use and this was the only solution i found that worked

and where i am using the conversion service

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/review")
class ReviewController(val reviewService: ReviewService, val conversionService: MyConversionService) {

    @PutMapping(params = ["upc", "userId"])
    fun updateReview(@RequestParam("upc") upc: Int, @RequestParam("userId") userId: Int, @RequestBody reviewDto: ReviewDto): ReviewDto {
        reviewDto.userId = userId
        reviewDto.upc = upc
        conversionService.addConverter(DtoToReviewConverter())
        println("can convert " + conversionService.canConvert(ReviewDto::class.java, Review::class.java))

        return conversionService.convert(reviewService.updateReview(upc, userId, conversionService.convert(reviewDto, Review::class.java) ?: throw CustomConversionException("There was a problem")), ReviewDto::class.java) ?: throw CustomConversionException("There was a problem")

    }

    @PostMapping(params = ["upc", "userId"])
    fun saveReview(@RequestParam("upc") upc: Int, @RequestParam("userId") userId: Int, @RequestBody reviewDto: ReviewDto): ReviewDto {
        reviewDto.userId = userId
        reviewDto.upc = upc
        return conversionService.convert(reviewService.saveReview(
            upc = upc,
            userId = userId,
            review = conversionService.convert(reviewDto, Review::class.java) ?: throw CustomConversionException("There was a problem")
        ), ReviewDto::class.java) ?: throw CustomConversionException("There was a problem")
    }

    @GetMapping(params = ["userId"])
    fun getReviewsByUser(@RequestParam("userId") userId: Int): List<ReviewDto> {
        return reviewService.getReviewsByUser(userId).map { conversionService.convert(it, ReviewDto::class.java) ?: throw CustomConversionException("There was a problem") }
    }

    @GetMapping(params = ["upc"])
    fun getReviewsByProduct(@RequestParam("upc") upc: Int): List<ReviewDto> {
        return reviewService.getReviewsByProduct(upc).map { conversionService.convert(it, ReviewDto::class.java) ?: throw CustomConversionException("There was a problem") }
    }
}
```

here is the stack trace

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.example.demo.datatranferobjects.ReviewDto] to type [com.example.demo.entities.Review]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at com.example.demo.controllers.ReviewController.updateReview(ReviewController.kt:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

i tried adding the repos to one of the working converter classes thinking it might stop working but it did still work

not sure where to go as the stack trace to me isnt that helpful

***Update*** I have made some progress i think and am pretty sure the issue has to do with the order spring is instantiating the beans. I am just not sure how to set everything up correctly now. Seems like if I could change how spring is doing the autowiring I could fix the issue

Comment: Could you post the definition of the Converter?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. what are you looking for? I thought i put the definition in the first code block

Comment: you have post the `OrderToDtoConverter` and `DtoToOrderConverter` which work for orders, but error is about the `Review`, so we need to see `Review` related converter. Which in your code is called `ReviewToDtoConverter` I believe.

Comment: wow i really wasnt paying attention. The implementations and errors are basically the same for both the orders which was posted and the reviews. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the likely cause is that the signature of the class `DtoToReviewConverter: Converter<ReviewDto,Review>` doesn't match the return type of the converter. So even though you've defined the Converter as returning an object of type `Review`, your converter method is returning an object of type `Review?` . The nullable type is fundamentally different from the non-nullable type in Kotlin. To fix this, you can update the generic type of your converter to be `Review?` or ensure the return type of your converter function is `Review`.

This article here discusses nullability and generics in Kotlin, see if that helps: https://medium.com/@igorwojda/kotlin-deep-dive-into-generics-nullability-9853d9a9f50d

Comment: So i was questioning that too and tried with the converter returning an optional and a non-optional value. I got the same result with both. See my latest update. I think the issue has to do with the order the beans are getting instantiated and how spring is autowiring them